# Find all ancestor nodes of a HierarchyId using a single SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to find a way to get all ancestor nodes of a given node using HierarchyID.  Every solution I've seen using HierarchyID seems to use either a CTE or a variable.  Is there a way to do this using a single select statement?

To make things simpler:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    EmpId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    EmpName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Position HierarchyID NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Employee (EmpName, Position)
VALUES ('CEO', '/'),
    ('COO', '/1/'),
    ('CIO', '/2/'),
    ('CFO', '/3/'),
    ('VP Financing', '/3/1/'),
    ('Accounts Receivable', '/3/1/1/'),
    ('Accountant 1', '/3/1/1/1/'),
    ('Accountant 2', '/3/1/1/2/'),
    ('Accountant 3', '/3/1/1/3/'),
    ('Accounts Payable', '/3/1/2/'),
    ('Accountant 4', '/3/1/2/1/'),
    ('Accountant 5', '/3/1/2/2/'),
    ('DBA', '/2/1/'),
    ('VP of Operations', '/1/1/')
```

Comment: a CTE solution *is* a single select statement, isn't it?

Comment: Generally, the solutions I've seen using CTEs are recursive, which is confusing.  Also, there's a select to define the CTE (rather two for the recursion) and one to pull the data from it.  I was wondering if there is a single statement that could be made without using CTEs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get "all parent nodes of a given node":

```
select *, position.GetAncestor(1), position.GetAncestor(1).ToString()
from employee
where position=hierarchyid::Parse('/3/1/')

EmpId  EmpName       Position  (No column name)  (No column name)
5      VP Financing  0x7AC0    0x78              /3/
```

but there will only ever be one due to the nature of hierarchies.

If you really want to get all immediate *children* nodes of a given node:

```
select * 
from employee 
where position.IsDescendantOf(hierarchyid::Parse('/3/1/'))=1
      and position.GetLevel()=hierarchyid::Parse('/3/1/').GetLevel()+1

EmpId  EmpName              Position
6      Accounts Receivable  0x7AD6
10     Accounts Payable     0x7ADA
```

-- EDIT

I see that you want all ancestor nodes. Perhaps try an approach like this:

```
select * 
from employee
where hierarchyid::Parse('/3/1/2/1/').IsDescendantOf(Position) = 1
```

or

```
select * from employee
where ( select position 
        from employee 
        where empname='Accountant 4' ).IsDescendantOf(Position) = 1
```

here is a CTE method for comparison:

```
with w as ( select * from employee where empname='Accountant 4'
            union all
            select e.*
            from employee e join w on(w.position.GetAncestor(1)=e.Position) )
select * from w;
```

Comment: I really like those.  They're very clean and easy to understand.  Much better than what I was coming up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @hid_Specific HIERARCHYID 

/** Assign your specific node path **/
SET @hid_Specific='/1/1/3/1/';

SELECT 
     hrchy_id,
     * 
FROM 
     tblHierarchyData 
WHERE 
     PATINDEX(hrchy_id.ToString()+'%',@hid_Specific.ToString())=1
```

Comment: please consider registering your account - that will allow you to login from multiple locations and allows you to regain access to your account if you forget the password, etc.  Also, please take the [tour] - thanks!

Comment: While code is almost always helpful, it's great if you can explain how your solution works, or why it's a good way to go.  Adding a link or two to the official documentation can help as well.